# How do I do strikethrough (line-through) in asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

How do I render a strikethrough (or line-through) in an `adoc` file?

Let's  presume I want to write "That technology is -c-r-a-p- not perfect."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per [Ascii Doc manual](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#migrate-deprecated), `[line-through]` is deprecated. You can test [here](https://asciidoclive.com/edit/scratch/1).

[Comment](https://github.com/maxandersen/gdoc2adoc/issues/7#issuecomment-233848677) from [Dan Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208063/dan-allen)

> It's important to understand that line-through is just a CSS role. Therefore, it needs support from the stylesheet in order to appear as though it is working.
>
> If I run the following through Asciidoctor (or Asciidoctor.js):
>
> `[.line-through]#strike#`
>
> I get:
>
> `<span class="line-through">strike</span>`
>
> The default stylesheet has a rule for this:
>
> `.line-through{text-decoration:line-through}`
>
> You would need to do the same.
>
> It is possible to customize the HTML that is generated using custom templates (Asciidoctor.js supports Jade templates). In that case, you'd override the template for inline_quoted, check for the `line-through` role and produce either an `<s>` or, preferably, a `<del>` instead of the span.

Answer (score 44):

```
That technology is [line-through]#crap# not perfect.
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're only targeting the HTML backend, you can insert HTML code verbatim via a passthrough context. This can be done inline by wrapping the parts in `+++`:

```
That technology is +++<del>+++crap+++</del>+++ not perfect.
```

This won't help you for PDF, DocBook XML, or other output formats, though.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide some context and explanation of how this code answers the question.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts: I've added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If the output is intended for HTML you can pass HTML.

> The `<s>` HTML element renders text with a strikethrough, or a line
> through it. Use the  element to represent things that are no longer
> relevant or no longer accurate.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s

To render as:

Example <strike>text</strike>.

use:

**1. Pass inline:**

```
Example +++<s>text</s>+++.
```

**2. Pass-through macro:**

```
Example pass:[<s>text</s>].
```

**3. Pass block:**

```
++++
Example <s>text</s>.
++++
```